# Antlr Matlab grammar lexing conflict

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexical-analysis

I've been using the Antlr Matlab grammar from [Antlr grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/matlab)

I found out I need to implement the ' Matlab operator. It is the [complex conjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrices-in-the-matlab-environment.html) operator, used as such

```
result = input'
```

I tried a straightforward solution of adding it to unary_expression as an option `postfix_expression '\''`

However, this failed to parse when multiple of these operators were used on a single line.

Here's a significantly simplified version of the grammar, still exhibiting the exact problem:

```
grammar Grammar;

unary_expression
   : IDENTIFIER
   | unary_expression '\''
   ;

translation_unit : unary_expression CR ;

STRING_LITERAL : '\'' [a-z]* '\'' ;

IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z] ;

CR : [\r\n] + ;
```

Test cases, being parsed as translation_unit:

```
"x''\n" //fails getNumberOfSyntaxErrors returns 1
"x'\n" //passes
```

The failure also prints the message `line 1:1 extraneous input '''' expecting CR` to stderr.

The failure goes away if I either remove STRING_LITERAL, or change the `*` to `+`. Neither is a proper solution of course, as removing it is entirely off the table, and mandating non-empty strings is not quite correct, though I might be able to live with it. Also, forcing non-empty string does nothing to help the real use case, when the input is something like `x' + y'` instead of using the operator twice.

For some reason removing `CR` from the grammar and `\n` from the tests also makes the parsing run without problems, but yet again is not a useable solution.

What can I do to the grammar to make it work correctly? I'm assuming it's a problem with lexing specifically because removing STRING_LITERAL or making it unable to match `''` makes it go away.

Comment: This is a good question, and one of the problems with Antlr--there is not a great way for the parser to influence the lexer. Here, you need context to tokenize this into either the single quote or a string literal. You can try to pass the parser state to the lexer, but it may not be enough information for you lexer to make a decision. Alternatively, you could try yanking the string literal and the complex conjugate transpose operator rule into rules in the parser.

Comment: I forgot to mention, you could in the lexer look around the single quote to gather context and decide what token to return.

Comment: @kaby76 do you happen to have an example of either? Ideally a grammar (from that grammars repo for example) which needs and does either of those?

Comment: I have no examples, so I took the Matlab grammar and added code to check parser state for transpose. See https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/Matlab. If there's backtracking in the parser (e.g., due to other semantic predicates), then this may not work. After considering yanking the string literal into the parser, you may not like that--you'd have to start a lexer mode to return individual characters. I think there's something like that in the Antlr grammar itself in grammars-v4. In either of these approaches, you have to split grammar, and push string literals into the lexer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lexer can never be made that context aware I think, but I don't know Matlab well enough to be sure. How could you check during tokenisation that these single quotes are operators:

```
x' + y';
```

while these are strings:

```
x = 'x' + ' + y';
```

?

Maybe you can do something similar as how in ECMAScript a `/` can be a division operator or a regex delimiter. In this grammar that is handled by a [predicate in the lexer](https://github.com/bkiers/ecmascript-parser/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/nl/bigo/ecmascriptparser/ECMAScript.g4#L773) that uses some [target code](https://github.com/bkiers/ecmascript-parser/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/nl/bigo/ecmascriptparser/ECMAScript.g4#L147) to check this.

If something like the above is not possible, I see no other way than to "promote" the creation of strings to the parser. That would mean removing `STRING_LITERAL` and introducing a parser rule that matches something like this:

```
string_literal
 : QUOTE ~(QUOTE | CR)* QUOTE
 ;

// Needed to match characters inside strings
OTHER
 : .
 ;
```

However, that will fail when a string like `'hi there'` is encountered: the space in between `hi` and `there` will now be skipped by the `WS` rule. So `WS` should also be removed (spaces will then get matched by the `OTHER` rule). But now (of course) all spaces will litter the token stream and you'll have to account for them in all parser rules (not really a viable solution).

All in all: I don't see ANTLR as a suitable tool in this case. You might look into parser generators where there is no separation between tokenisation and parsing. Google for "PEG" and/or "scannerless parsing".

Comment: The predicate in the lexer seems to be working wonderfully, the parsing no longer craps itself on the likes of `x' + y'` and produces the expected parse tree. Given that I didn't want to rework my whole project, that's probably as close to ideal as I'm gonna get.

Comment: The transpose problem has been tackled in SMOP, apparently successfully. It may be helpful look at its code. You can start here: https://github.com/victorlei/smop/blob/master/smop/backend.py

Comment: Google led me here because of @Bart  comments regarding Matlab and PEG. I had an associated question. Is there a simple way of converting an existing grammar such as either Antlr Matlab grammar or that within SMOP: https://github.com/victorlei/smop/blob/master/smop/parse.py  and converting them to a PEG form?

Comment: Not that I am aware of @RobBW

Comment: There is also a fork of SMOP based on it which addresses the Transpose problem here: https://github.com/led02/mlabpy/blob/master/src/mlabpy/parser.py